# onClick dispatches an action. How do i wait for my dispatch to complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I had this executeOrder function in my child component. this was directly calling the API to get data from backend in this way

```
const executeOrder = async (data, actions) => {
      value = await getToken(
        props.orderTotal
      );
      return value.ecToken;

  };
```

As you can see, i was using `await` function in my `executeOrder`. With this, it would wait for the execution to complete and then provide me a return `value.ecToken`

Since i am using REACT, i had to make use of action dispatcher and make a API call from my Redux saga file. So i created an action dispatcher and made a API call this way.

```
const executeOrder = (data, actions) => {
    props.initiateIdentity(props.orderTotal); //ACTION DISPATCHER
    console.log("2");
    return props.ecToken;
  };
```

Now how do i ensure this action dispatcher completes it execution ? Because, i am dispatching the action and making a API call. The response of the API call, i am putting it in a state and passing that state value from main component to child component via `mapStateToProps`

By the time `props.initiateIdentity(props.orderTotal)` is getting executed, it goes to next line `return props.ecToen` and since this value is still not provided back from API call, i get a blank value.

How do i ensure this action dispatcher has finished its task ?? Someone please help me

PS- here is my SAGA

```
function* initiateIdentity(action: TInitiateIdentPayPal) {
  try {
    const resp = yield call(
      getToken,
      orderTotal,
    );
    console.log("1");
    yield put(savePiBlob(resp));
  } catch (err) {
  } finally {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, You have to create 3 status constant of a actions and you get the response in function* in saga file. Your saga function should be look like:

```
function* callApiInSaga(actions) {
  try {
    const data = yield callApiByAxiosOrFetch({ type: actions.data });
    yield put({ 
      type: constants.CALL_API_SUCCESS,
      data,
    }); `// if your function calling api is executed, and you get response from server, put({}) in saga will have you transfer data from saga to reducer. and you can use data via mapDispatchToProps:`
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: constants.CALL_API_FAILED,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i have all of this in my saga. The problem is `return value.ecToken;` gets executed even before the saga completes execution.

Comment: I have put 2 console.log now. Ideally, the console should log "1" and then "2". But its logging "2" and then "1". please see where i put console.log in above code.

Comment: because you start an action in executeOrder function, it surely go first. you have to use ComponentDidMount to wait response API.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you cannot achieve it that way.

In the world of Redux, do mutation(by dispatching actions) and get the latest state are two sorts of operations and never mixed out. redux will resolve the updated state somehow, but cannot guarantee the exact timeslot.

Comment: Cn i use something like this to ensure it waits till i get state values to props ? 

setTimeout(() => {
      props.initiateIdentity(props.orderTotal);
    }, 20000);

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea.  In redux way, when you make the subscription properly, you will get the latest value of state in time.  If you want to make sure the value is there before some operation/view changes, go ahead to check the value of state somewhere. Or, you can add additional flag variable in redux store  like 'API_SUCCESS' and its value is either true or false. In your application you will be able the know if the ecToken is ok to use or not by checking the value of 'API_SUCCESS' .

Comment: @Pengson- can i use javascript await in my action dispatch ? something like await  props.initiateIdentity(props.orderTotal);

Comment: Yes, you can if the function is async but I doubt it will not work as you expected. I recommend you read the official doc https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started to understand the concept of Redux.

Answer (score 1):

If you store `ecToken` in your redux store then you don't need to return its value from `executeOrder`. Instead when you call `savePiBlob(resp)` you can update `ecToken` in your reducer. The parent can access `ecToken` with `mapStateToProps`.

Or if you do want to return `ecToken` from the child component then use `componentDidUpdate` to check if `ecToken` is updated and then return `ecToken` by calling a parent method.

```js
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.ecToken !==null && this.props.ecToken !== prevProps.ecToken) 
      {
        //call parent method here
      }
   }
```

My if condition might not be accurate. you can add whatever works for you

Comment: Hi Amruta, i am using useEffect instead of componentDidUpdate now. Its as below 
useEffect(() => {
    if (this.props.ecToken !==null && this.props.ecToken !== "") 
      {
        return props.ecToken;
      }
  });

do you know how i can return from a react lifecycle hook. i want to return props.ecToken but its not allwing me. it gives a error as Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void)'.

Comment: @user3019647  I have less experience with hooks, but from what I remember you can only return a function or an undefined from useEffect. `return props.ecToken;` however, is returning a string. You can call a method with `ecToken` as its parameter, and in that method assign `ecToken` to some variable.  ```useEffect(() => { if (this.props.ecToken !==null && this.props.ecToken !== "") { return this.method(props.ecToken;) } });```